# Mongoose updaes only first element in the list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am wokring with mongoose in Nodejs. I have strange problem that when I am trying to update the objects in DB by ids, only the first 'id' is being updated. Here is my code:

```
user.update({'_id': { $in: req.body.ids}}, 
{ $addToSet: { forms: { $each: req.body.forms} } })
```

I checked the array of ids and there are 3 of them, but I get the response from the update:

```
{ n: 1,
nModified: 1,
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User **multi: true** option of update method. By default only first document found by the query is updated.

```
user.update({'_id': { $in: req.body.ids}}, 
{ $addToSet: { forms: { $each: req.body.forms} } }, {multi: true})
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you